# Mac OSX Lion or Mountain Lion GUI wireframing kit for Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mac, interface-design, osx

Is anyone aware of a wireframing kit for Illustrator (or any  vector based template) that encompasses GUI elements from Mac OSX Lion or Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's also [a paid one here](http://guitoolkits.com/mac-os-x-gui-toolkit/). It says it's available for Illustrator, Fireworks, Visio, OmniGraffle, Axure, Keynote and PowerPoint, and the Illlustrator single license is apparently something like $24.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be vector? [Here](http://dribbble.com/shots/233227-Lion-Ui-Kit-Preview) is a raster one for Photoshop.

[image: OSX Mockup]

Answer (score 0):

There is a Sketch vector UI kit http://yosemiteui.com

You can export it to PDF and import in Illustrator.